# Есть ли смысл использовать собственные реализации базовых АТД в C++?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, типы-данных, функциональное-программирование, стандарт

Задался вопросом, имеет ли смысл **в настоящее время** использовать собственные реализации таких типов данных как связный список/стек/очередь/словарь? Именно для выполнения реальных задач, а не в учебных целях. Казалось бы, стандарт языка С++ на данный момент предоставляет большое количество инструментов, но несмотря на это, в некоторых проектах всё ещё продолжают использовать самописные реализации тех или иных АТД. В том редком случае, когда стандартные средства уступают в производительности самописным, логично, что выбор вряд ли будет в пользу стандартных. Но в большинстве случаев нет какой-либо критичной разницы между двумя подходами. Так стоит ли игра свеч?

Comment: Ну, там, где *измерения* показывают, что написание своего, *не универсального*, *основанного на знании предметной области* АТД дает преимущество - почему бы и нет? Там, где это просто изобретение велосипеда, но с плохо прикрученными колесами - понятно, не имеет смысла... Да, мы же не говорим про **учебу**?

Comment: Нет, я имел ввиду именно практическую работу над реальными проектами.
Насколько я знаю, в большинстве случаев нет особой разницы между использованием готовых и собственных реализаций. Потому-то меня этот вопрос и настиг.

Comment: "предоставляет большое количество инструментов" - да вы что, стандартная библиотека куцая и убогая, удобные вещи из буста в нее десятилетиями переползают.

Comment: Есть ли какие-то наглядные примеры, подтверждающие ваш факт?

Comment: Если стандартные структуры решают вашу задачу - используйте их. Если нет - пишите свои специфичные структуры. Но вот простопереписывать, например, стек или связанный список, без веских причин, смысла не имеет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Реализация контейнеров и алгоритмов в STL или Boost - веселая штука. Их делают максимально унифицированными (в основном для покрытия максимального кол-ва задач) и очень тщательно проверяют на быстродействие и т.д.
2. Их пишут не один десяток людей, а ревьювят его вообще все ). Это дает гарантию что конкретная реализация будет максимально удовлетворять потребностям большинства.
3. Время когда люди писали свои "общие" контейнера и алгоритмы наверное прошло. Но во в задачах (пример: Вам нужен произвольный доступ, и ассоциотивность) - да надо писать свой костыль.
4. В стандартах очень много ассемблерных вставок для оптимизации производительности, и поэтому я не думаю что компилятор родит более вменяемый код, чем тот над которым посидели оптимизаторы.

ИМХО: В реальных задачах надо брать готовое, а не рожать что-то (ибо дорого) сейчас вообще большинство ничего не кодит (дешевле найти готовое и пришить), что разумеется пичалька